# Why Java needs classpath at runtime

Tags: java, jvm, classpath

In Java we set the classpath at compile time to compile Java files, but why do we need to set the classpath at runtime? Any specific reason why the JVM needs the classpath to run `.class` files?

Comment: Without it the JVM wouldn't know where to look for classes.

Comment: This cannot be specified at compile time because you may deploy your software with different version on a different machine with different paths as you development PC or build server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files on the classpath provide the actual executable code (in Java `.class` files) that the JVM needs to run.

Comment: Native libraries are not loaded via the CLASSPATH.

Comment: @EJP It's been too long (plenty long enough?) since I did JNI, and I forgot you have to extract the file yourself.

Comment: @chrylis so the class dependancy remains upto run time?

Answer (score 0):

> In Java we set the classpath at compile time to compile Java files

Do we? I don't.

> but why do we need to set the classpath at runtime?

So the JVM knows where it can find the classes.

Comment: yes of cource, at compile without classpath compiler gives error. isn't it? So according to you why we need classpath at compile time?

Comment: @Meet The compiler only needs the classpath if there are references in the classes being compiled to classes that aren't in the classes being compiled or their source code package system or the JDK.

Comment: yes, you are right, i also meant that i.e we need classpath at compile time only for third party jars.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons that I see, is that if I need for some reasons to have the libraries required by my app scattered across multiple mountpoints/drives/partitions or even folders, I would not be able to specify to the JVM where my code is. As a workaround, the JVM could look throughout the whole file-system and index stuff, but how efficient/fast would that be?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Often people think compiling makes for a stand-alone application without the need to point at dependencies. But it does not.

If your code has no dependencies, then you do not need to set a classpath.

You may need/want to include -cp at runtime:

1. To specify where to look for third-party and user-defined files your class requires at runtime (*.jar, *.class, *.properties, etc).
2. To override what the CLASSPATH environment variable is set to.

Answer (score -1):

**CLASSPATH** is an environmental variable used by Java Virtual Machine to locate the class files(including main class).

Alternatively you can pass **-cp** or **-class-path** as a argument to JVM to specify the class paths where your main class depends on.

For example,

```
export CLASSPATH=/opt/javatv:/opt/mhp:/opt/main-class;
java MainClass
```

(or)

```
java -cp /opt/javatv;/opt/mhp;/opt/main-class MainClass;
```

(or)

```
java -class-path /opt/javatv;/opt/mhp;/opt/main-class MainClass;
```

Comment: I couldn't remove my accidental click, and can only choose +1 or -1. Your answer is okay for the question of how to use classpath. But the question is "why is it needed at runtime"?

Comment: @WineGoddess JVM uses that variable while it trying to load classes at Runtime. JVM comes into picture only during the run-time.